# WordPress accordion integration with current page

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

In a web site having a sidebar accordion with two section. It is also an clickable link having an inner page. But the accordion selection is not not correctly selected in the detail page. Does anyone know the solution?

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"> 
    <div class="list-group"> 
        <?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'test', 'order'=> 'ASC' ); 
        query_posts($args); 
        if ( have_posts() ) : 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                <a class="list-group-item" style="padding-left:30px !important;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                </a> 
            <?php endwhile; 
        endif; ?> 
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code and the details of what you have tried and what doesn't work or any errors.

Comment: <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="list-group">
     <?php
     $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'post_type' => 'test',
     'order'=> 'ASC'
     );
      query_posts($args); 
        if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
     ?>
     <a class="list-group-item" style="padding-left:30px !important;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
              </div>
              </div>

Comment: here is the page link :      http://example.com/test/test_name/